# javascript file type check not working for jpeg but does work for png

Tags: javascript

I check the file type before uploading to my server, but the file type check only works for png and now jpeg:

```
for(var j = 0; j < $files.length; j++) {
  if(!$files[j].type.match('image/png') || !$files[j].type.match('image/jpeg')) {
    $scope.all_files_images = false;
  }
}
```

When the type is *image/jpeg*, `$scope.all_files_images = false;` is executed and it shouldn't be. Works fine for png. I checked the type and everything looks fine.

Comment: have you tried using the new html5 file api instead??

Comment: You might see if this similar thread helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345755/js-or-jquery-file-type-match-for-jpg-and-png-only

Comment: I bet it doesn't work for .png files after you add the .jpg test as in the above code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is broken.  Your code says, "if it's not PNG OR it's not JPG then ..."

If it's either one, it still fails because then it's not the other one. In other words, if it *is* a .png file, then, of course, that means it's *not* a .jpg file, so it the test thinks it's an error.

Change `||` to `&&`. Then it'll be, "if it's not PNG AND it's not JPG then ...", which is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a string, e.g. `'image/png'` to the `match()` method.  Unfortunately, `match()` doesn't expect a string, it expects a `RegExp` object... like this:

`match(/gif|png|jpg|jpeg/);`

Comment: It'll convert the string to a regex.